# The SwiftUI cost me whole morning just build a tiny button, please save me

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm just trying to build a list that look like below, however, the SwiftUI Button drive me crazy and I wanna make corner radius 10, but the corner actually always disappears.

This is the row I want, notice that the 'Follow' button has cornerRadius and a proper height

[image: This is the row I want, notice that the 'Follow' button has cornerRadius and a proper height,]

However after I searched tons of damn answer, what I can only got is this, the corner even disappears!!!:

[image: However after I searched tons of damn answer, what I can only got is this, the corner even disappears!!!]

```
Button(action: {

            }) {
                if person.isInKnock {
                    Text("Follow").font(.system(size: 14)).foregroundColor(Color(ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.THEME.THEME_COLOR))).padding()
                }
                else {
                    Text("Invite to Knock").font(.system(size: 14)).foregroundColor(Color(ColorUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.THEME.THEME_COLOR))).padding()
                }

        }.frame(height: CGFloat(30)).border(Color.gray, width: CGFloat(1)).cornerRadius(CGFloat(10))
```

Comment: If you would like us to debug the code you have, you need to show us it. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59073892/edit) link and add your code to your question

Answer (score 2):

Apple has been switching up the modifier functions constantly, so it's annoying to keep up with all the changes. Here's a working solution I've found:

```
Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Follow")
                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemTeal))
                .bold()
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.gray)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                )
        }
```

This produces the following image:

[image: Rounded Rectangle Button]

The key is overlaying a `RoundedRectangle` and changing the stroke and corner radius. `.stroke()` changes the shape itself, while `.border()` changes the view of the rectangle. Hope this helps!